# Get number of redis-Keys that have been en-queued for more than 5 minutes

Tags: redis, sidekiq

We want to monitor our Sidekiq process and see if some of them are failing. This normally leads to a situation where a Sidekiq-job hangs forever, in case there's an error.

My question is now, how can I get via redis-cli the number of jobs, which have been in the queue for more than 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do exactly what you ask.  Read this:

How to monitor your queue latency https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring#monitoring-queue-latency

Comment: How do I get the latency with redis-cli?